# uploading and downloading files in yii PHP

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to upload files in yii, but the files are not being uploaded. Could someone help please.
My controller code looks like this

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $this->hasPrivilege(Acl::ACTION_CREATE);
        $this->pageTitle = Lang::t(Constants::LABEL_CREATE . ' ' . $this->resourceLabel);

        $model = new AflTestFile();
        $model_class_name = $model->getClassName();

        if (isset($_POST[$model_class_name])) {

            $model->attributes = $_POST[$model_class_name];
            $model->test_file=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'test_file');
        if($model->save()) {
                $model->test_file->saveAs(Yii::getPathOfAlias('/uploads'));

            $error_message = CActiveForm::validate($model);
            $error_message_decoded = CJSON::decode($error_message);
            if (!empty($error_message_decoded)) {
                echo CJSON::encode(array('success' => false, 'message' => $error_message));
            } else {
                $model->save(FALSE);
                echo CJSON::encode(array('success' => true, 'message' => Lang::t('SUCCESS_MESSAGE'), 'redirectUrl' => UrlManager::getReturnUrl($this->createUrl('index'))));
            }
            }

            Yii::app()->end();
        }
```

Comment: Look for jquery Uploder,good library for uploding images and documents https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Answer (score 0):

I use [EAjaxUpload](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/eajaxupload) extension and it is good. but if you need a uploader with full features(like pause,resume,...) you can use
[PlUpload](http://plupload.com/) plugin.

Answer (score -1):

I've had similar issues. Not sure what your setup is for $model but try using getInstanceByName and using the upload instance from there.

```
$upload = CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName("test_file");
$file['name'] = $upload->name;
$file['tmp_name'] = $upload->tempName;
$file['size'] = $upload->size;
```

Also check if your `<form>` element is setup properly and you're using the right method and encryption type attributes (i.e. `<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` for files)

You can also debug to make sure that your file is being uploaded and that $_FILE variable is set correctly.